# Subscriptions and ngZone

Tags: meteor, zone, angular2-meteor

What is the difference between :

```
this.subscribe('apples', () => {
  ngZone.run(()=>{
    this.apple= Apples.findOne( this.id);
  });
```

and *(line 1 and 2 are switched)*

```
ngZone.run(()=>{
  this.subscribe('apples', () => {
    this.apple= Apples.findOne( this.id);
  });
```

When looking at [meteor-component](https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor/blob/master/modules/meteor_component.ts), wrapping the `subscribe` in the `run` should work.

However, when doing my own implementation of meteor-component to call not Meteor.subscribe but [SubsManager.subscribe](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kadirahq/subs-manage) the first example does not works, only the second.

Could you please explain me the difference ? Bonus: hint on why in my case the 2nd one only works.

Comment: I don't use Angular, but it looks like the first example sets up a subscription named 'apples', then uses a callback to call `ngZone.run()`, whereas the second one calls `ngZone.run()` first, then sets up the subscription to 'apples'.  Now, why you would do one over the other depends on Angular.